# Write a own program for Signature Capture on Android

Tags: android

I'm a beginner on android.Right now I'm developing a own application for Signature Capture on android. I already google several time. I found somethings.Most of the android developer recommend to use **TouchPaint.java** and **FingerPaint.java**. So I start to implement with **TouchPaint.java** then I followed this [Video Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iO4nWkZ5njk) from YouTube. But I got the following errors

**onTouchEvent** on TouchPaint.java.

```
event.getHistoricalTouchMajor(j, i)
```

The method getHistoricalTouchMajor(int, int) is undefined for the type MotionEvent.
[image]

```
event.getTouchMajor(j)
```

The method getTouchMajor(int) is undefined for the type MotionEvent.
[image]

Please help me I've no idea how to solve those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Api level is too low so raise it to API level 9.  API 9 is Android 2.3 so you won't be able to install this on 2.1 and 2.2 devices which is the majority of the Android install base.

[image]

## Further more detail ::

Comment: Thanks, I used API Level 8 that why not support getHistoricalTouchMajor function.

Answer (score 1):

Just as    @Dk.nik mentioned, it's the problem of API level.
So you might want to reconfig your Project to match.

On the menu Project->Properties, select Android from treeview, on the right pane, Android Build Target, select the correct the API level.